# Identityserver4 ApiResource and IdentityResource with same names

Tags: api, scope, resources, identity, identityserver4

I'm pretty new to the OAuth2, and OpenID Connect space, and I'm trying to build an API and secure it using IdentityServer4. I created the following resources:-

```
public static class MyResources
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>()
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResource("someResource", "some description", new [] { "something" })
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>()
        {
            new ApiResource("someResource", "some other description", new [] { "somethingElse" })
        };
    }
}
```

So as you can see that I have a **IdentityResource called someResource** and also a **ApiResource by the same name called someResource**. Finally, in my Clients configuration, I have defined the following **Client Scopes which includes someResource** for access

```
public static class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "MyClientId",
                ClientName = "My Client Name",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "someResource"
                },
                RequireConsent = true,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I run the application, this is what I see on the consent screen

[ID4 Consent Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3880H.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, the consent screen is giving both the IdentityResource as well as the ApiResource called someResource. Is this design intentional and the naming of the resources has to be carefully planned by you so as not to have a conflict. I would expect 2 different resources having the same name to throw at least a runtime error because client scopes can only differentiate by name and not the resource type. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope names must be unique.

If you are using the "simplified" way of creating resources - scopes with the same name are implicitly created.

IOW - don't do that ;)